# Django template not posting checkboxes data

Tags: django, post, checkbox, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django and web developing.

I have a simple template that has in a table some data with a form with checkboxes and external off this table a submit button, but all in same form.

```
    <form  action="{% url 'delLogin' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr><th>Total: {{ object_list.count }}</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
        <tr><th>Login</th><th>Customer</th></th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>

        {% for obj in object_list %}
          <tr>
            <td> <a href="{% url 'DetailLogin' obj.id_login %}"> {{ obj.id_login }}</a></td>
            <td> <a href="{% url 'DetailCust' obj.customer %}"> {{ obj.customer }} </a></td>       
            <td> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{ obj.id_login }}" value="{{ obj.id_login }}"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete selected">
    </form>
</div>
```

This should post data to another view:

```
def deleteObjects(request):
template = 'Gestione/delObj.html'
objects = []
for obj, value in request.POST.items():
    objects.append(value)
context = {'objects' : objects}
return render(request, template, context)
```

rendered to this template:

```
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{% if objects %}
{% for object in objects %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

The page is loaded without errors, but "objects" are not displayed and I can't figure why.

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think request.POST.items() is not returning what you think its returning. You should raise a ValueError or something to see what its returning, and then you can modify your for-loop to appropriately parse it.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is dynamic forms:

**Own form class:**

```
from django import forms

class DeleteForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, own_param, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeleteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field'] = own_param
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's not possible to proceed like you've described here. The issue is that I have a list of objects in a table and every row has a checkbox to send data, so the number of objects passed to the form is variable.

Answer (score -1):

"The page is loaded without errors, but "objects" are not displayed...."
This line caught my attention
The problem is where you are trying to assign the name and value of your check-box to the objectlist variable.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ obj.id_login }}" value="{{ obj.id_login }}"/>
```

instead write:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{ obj.id_login }}/>
```